# Wrong assemblies on multiple instances of webapp in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, multiple-instances

Let's say I have a website on the azure webapps which is always scaled at 10 instances. 
And then I do some code changes on the website and re-deploy to the webapp which still is scaled up to 10 instances. Would it be possible that something might go wrong and that not all the instances assemblies would get updated? is this an issue that could happen?

Haven't found much about it when googling but perhaps anyone here would know more about this scenario.

BR
Joe

Answer (score 1):

Your application files are placed in a network share and not copied to many servers. The share is then mapped to the machine(s) running IIS as d:\home. The folder contains your app files, logs from iis, etc.  When you deploy your file, they are placed in the common UNC share.  So all the instances see the same files.
More details here:   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-available-operating-system-functionality/

Comment: What if the webapps use local cache?
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-local-cache/